# Order of nomenclature precedence among these functional groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

The order of precedence for functional groups I have so far is:

1. carboxylic acid
2. ester
3. amide
4. aldehyde
5. ketone
6. alcohol
7. amine
8. multiple bonds
9. ether
10. organic halide

I'm pretty confident that from 1 to 7, I have the order of precedence right. But from 8 onwards, I'm not too sure. Could someone help verify that the list I've got is right or help me correct it?

Comment: @L to the V are you talking about precedence in the context of IUPAC nomenclature?

Comment: You've mentioned 'these functional groups' in your statement. But, Halogen, nitro group are never functional groups.

Answer (score 3):

From [Master Organic Chemistry](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/02/14/table-of-functional-group-priorities-for-nomenclature/): It looks like your table is correct

[image]

Comment: Wait...how come alkene is above alkyne? I thought triple bonds were of higher precedence than double bonds.

Comment: I had trouble cross-referencing my textbook, but i came across other online sources that agree with my answer. Do you have any material that might suggest otherwise?

Comment: The so-called “Table of Functional Group Priorities For Nomenclature” shown on masterorganicchemistry.com tries to combine the seniority order of suffixes with prefixes and endings. This can be misleading and result in wrong names. In particular, there is no suffix ‘-ane’, ‘-ene’ or ‘-yne’ (these are endings), and multiple bonds (and all groups that follow in that table) are actually not considered in the seniority order. Please do not use such sources.

Comment: @Loong do you have a recommended resource? I'm open to altering this answer with a more legitimate source. Could be in the style of a community wiki.